# Why is there no reputation change in meta

Tags: discussion

Why is there no reputation change in [Apple.meta.stackexchange.com](http://Apple.meta.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I've removed the feature request tag. If you want to nominate that we should ask for meta reputation, feel free to make that clear and single request with the tag. Lay out what you feel it should do so people can vote on it : - )

Comment: [Why doesn't Meta Stack Overflow have real reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297639/4751173)

Comment: Maybe it could be changed voting wouldn’t change reputation but writing an accepted answer and some other things would change reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't around when the meta on the main trilogy was formed, but meta we down vote things we don't want to see. It's like a caucus or straw vote. If I raise a controversial issue and everyone disagrees - the down votes shouldn't take away from my reputation on the main site and you don't really earn reputation here to participate - you earn reputation on the main site to qualify to ask and answer here.

I'm sure there are some really nice blog posts on Meta Stack Exchange now that that's been split off from the SO meta.